# Converting xml response to Array with php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

Please i'm developping a php application,  i want to know how to convert the xml reponse of a soap webservice into strings or array or json, i want to insert the values returned by the webservice into my database.

here is my xml respnse:

```
   <env:Envelope xmlns:env="">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <soap:getUserInfoResponse xmlns:soap="">
         <getUserInfoResult>
            <userInformation>
               <detailuserInformationList>
                  <detailuserInformation>
                     <Name>Alex</Name>
                     <alias>Lex</alias>
                     <age>24</age>
                     <function>agent</function>
                     <birthdate>1</birthdate>
                     <birthmounth>02</birthmounth>
                     <birthyear>1990</birthyear>
                     <address>wall street</address>
                     <civility>mr</civility>
                     <gender>m</gender>
                  </detailuserInformation>
               </detailuserInformationList>
               <lastLogin>14:22</lastLogin>
               <userId>A52241</userId>
               <cnxTimes>125</cnxTimes>
            </userInformation>
            <requestTag/>
         </getUserInfoResult>
      </soap:getUserInfoResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

and here is my php code, calling the ws:

```
$client = new SoapClient('$url', array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
$client->__setLocation('$url');

$response = $client->__soapCall("getUserInfo", array( parameters...);

print htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());
```

Comment: What programming language you're using?

Comment: Use this to automatically translate XML response into array: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: i'm using SoapClient to call the webservice and it works but i'm getting troubles when parsing the result, it's displayed in block, can't extract the different values on php variables

Comment: update your question with your code.

Comment: it's done !!!! check my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use php SoapClient class

[SoapClient class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

If you generate WSDL use 
[NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

Comment: i'm using SoapClient to call the webservice and it works but i'm getting troubles when parsing the result, it's displayed in block, can't extract the different values on php variables

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check what do you have in `$response` in your code:

```
print htmlspecialchars($response);
```

Sceondly, this is proper way or working with `SoapClient`:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 0));
$response = $client->getUserInfo( /* parameters */ );
```

You'll get array in $response. You can laso view request and response XML with `$client->__getLastRequest()` and `$client->__getLastResponse()`.